# charging light on in laptop with battery removed

Tags: laptop, motherboard, battery

I hope this is the right place for this question.
I have an LG R310 laptop. Recently the adapter connector started playing up, so I got a second hand replacement adapter of the same rating. The adapter was a cheap type (I know I made a mistake) and faulty.. it made a low buzzing sound when plugged in and not connected to the laptop. It didn't make the noise when connected to the laptop. Foolishly I used this adapter for several weeks.

One day the adapter stopped working. The led didnt work and it was not charging. It had also drained the laptop's battery to 0%. I then got an original replacement adapter. Now I can use the laptop on power but the battery does not charge. The charging light does not come on. The interesting thing is that when I remove the battery the charging light comes on and stays on after I insert the battery back (the battery still does not charge).

I need to know if the faulty adapter damaged the motherboard or if its just a problem with the battery. I have a multimeter and I prefer not to open the laptop.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's possible the low quality adapter wore down you battery faster than it should have. Also how long did you leave your battery at 0 before getting the correct adapter?

Comment: I got it the next day. It would not start otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my question as others might have the same issue. The problem was indeed with the battery. I put a new battery and everything started working fine. It seems that the faulty charger had completely drained the battery to a state from which it was not recoverable. I also got a new charger to ensure this does not happen again.

Answer (score 1):

It is definitely possible that your battery is damaged or heavily degraded, and it is also possible that your motherboard is damaged. When something that feeds power to a device does not operate properly, a lot of bad things can happen. Without knowing exactly what that adapter was really feeding your computer, it is hard to say, but motherboards are fickle devices. Slight variants in power can do a lot of damage. If you are comfortable opening up the laptop, you can look for visible signs of damage (blown capacitors, burn marks, etc) and you can try a new battery to see how it acts. Short of that, there isn't a whole lot you can do at this point.